# Developing player rankings with ELO

Tags: algorithm, function, system

I recently created a tournament system that will soon lead into player rankings. Basically, after players are done with the tournament, they are given a rank based on how they did in the tournament. So the person who won the tournament will have the most points and be ranked #1, while the second will have the second most points  and be ranked #2, and so on...

However, after they are ranked in the new rankings, they can challenge other members and have a way to play other members and change their ranks. So basically (using a ranking system), if Player A who is ranked #2 beats Player B who is ranked #1, Player A will now become #1.

I've also decided that if a player wants to compete in the rankings but was not present during the tournament, they can sign up after the tournament, and will be given the lowest possible rank with the lowest points (but they have a chance to move up).

So now, I am wanting to know which way should I go about planning this. When I convert the players from tournament to match rankings, I have to identify them with points in order to rank them. I decided this seems like the best way to do it.

```
1  1000
2  900
3  800
4  700
5  600
6  500
7  400
8  300
9  200
10 100
```

After looking on the internet I've decided it would be wise to use ELO to give players their new rank after they players have matched against each other.. I went about it on this page: http://www.lifewithalacrity.com/2006/01/ranking_systems.html

So if I go about it this way, lets say I have rank #10 facing rank #1. According to the website above, my formula is:

```
R' = R + K * (S - E)
```

and the rating of #10 only has 100 points where #1 has 1,000.
So after doing the math rank #10's expected value of beating #1 is:

```
1 / [ 1 + 10 ^ ( [1000 - 100] / 400) ]
= 0.55%
```

So
     100 + 32 * (1 - 0.52)
     = 115.36

The problem I have with ELO is it makes no sense. After A rank such as #10 beats #1, he should not gain something as low as 15 points. I'm not sure if i'm doing the math wrong, or if I'm splitting up the points wrong. Or maybe I shouldn't use ELO at all? Any suggestions would be very helpful

Answer (score 1):

Don't get offended, it is your table that doesn't make sense.

Elo system is based on the premise that a rating is an accurate estimate of the strength, and difference of ratings accurately predicts an outcome of a match (a player better by 200 point is expected to score 75%). If an actual outcome does not agree with a prediction, it means that ratings do not reflect strength, hence must be adjusted according to how much an actual outcome differs from the predicted.

An official (as in FIDE) Elo system has few arbitrary arbitrary constants (e.g. 200/75 gauge, `Erf` as predictor, etc); choosing them (reasonably) different may lead to a different rating values, yet would result (in a long run) in the same ranking. There is some interesting math behind this assertion; this is not a right place to get into details.

Now back to your table. It assigns the rating based on the place, not on the points scored. The champion gets 1000 no matter whether she swept the tournament with an absolute 100% result, or barely made it among equals. These points do not estimate the strength of the participants.

So my advise is to abandon the table altogether, assign each new player an entry rating (say, 1000; it really doesn't matter as long as you are consistent), and stick to Elo from the very beginning.

Comment: This wouldn't work because the tournaments are what create the "placements" that would then lead into the ELO system... I guess I should find something other than ELO?

Comment: Sorry I didn't quite get the question. For a very first tournament all players are assigned an entry rating (unless there is an _a priory_  strength estimate). just like the generic case. PS: Elo is spelled Elo, not ELO -- it is a last name of Arpad Elo.

Comment: Ok. Let me try to explain this. Anyone can join the tournament, and once they join it and compete they are given a placement. Here's an example: http://i.gyazo.com/f268c04e9cf204d974775fefc8076aa0.png Achilles would be ranked #1, rjg 2 would be ranked #2 and so on. Then they will be given points after this that would make them arranged like so (#1 would have most points, #2 would have second most points). However, people that couldn't compete in the tournament can sign up and will be given 100 points and be able to compete against these guys using Elo. This way new rankings can be determined.